# input.read() never returns -1

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am writing a proxy server in Java.

Initially, I do (simplified)

```
server = new ServerSocket(5568);
incoming = server.accept();
input = incoming.getInputStream();

...

outgoing = new Socket(host, 80);
output = outgoing.getOutputStream();
output.write(inputbuffer, 0, i);
```

where inputbuffer is some collection of bytes received so far (I read the incoming data up until the part where I know the host header, and then open a connection to the server and send what I have so far).  So server is my welcome socket, input is the data coming to my proxy from the client, and output is the data to the serve from my proxy.

Next, I want the output from the server to be written to the client in parallel with the client still possibly writing stuff to the server.  So I create a separate thread to read from the client:

```
final InputStream finalInput = input;
final OutputStream finalOutput = output;
Thread sendingStuff = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        int c;
        while ((c = finalInput.read()) != -1){
            finalOutput.write((byte)c);
            finalOutput.flush();
        }
        finalInput.close();
        finalOutput.close();
    }
}
sendingStuff.start();
```

Finally, I have a different section in the main thread to read from the server and write that to the client.

```
InputStream reverseInput = outgoing.getInputStream();
OutputStream reverseOutput = incoming.getOutputStream();
int c;
while ((c = reverseInput.read()) != -1){
    reverseOutput.write((byte)c);
    reverseOutput.flush();
}
reverseInput.close();
reverseOutput.close();
```

What happens is I get input, and send output, but the browser spins forever and the line in the thread that's reading from the client never gets a -1 signal.

A lot of the time I get errors that say things like "invalid header name" or "your browser sent a request that the server could not understand" and I think it has to do with this problem I'm having.  One time I even got an IOException: Socket Closed on the line that reads from the client.

So why isn't the client sending an EOF?  And is this the right way to go about doing this?

Comment: This seems like a multithreading problem. Can you expand on your simplified initial code? It seems like you are calling `read` and `write` simultaneously on the same streams. InputStream/OutputStream only go one way and calling read/write methods advances them. That would be why you are getting invalid reads/writes, because both threads are reading/writing simultaneously and getting incomplete data. Same with no EOF, if the output stream is writing to the same place you are reading from you are getting an endless IO loop.

Comment: Does the thread that is reading from the server read -1?

Comment: I think it's because my HTTP request has Connection:  keep-alive.  How do I handle this?

Comment: Don't flush inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

"I think it's because my HTTP request has Connection: keep-alive. How do I handle this?"
I think maybe you can just open your socket once for one connection. 
Try to have flag like isNewConnection. set it to true at first and after the connection is initiated, set it to false.